# Bigquery select rows where the logtime is below min(value) of other table logtime

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let say I have the following two tables :

Table 1:

```
ID     log_time 
1      2013-10-12
1      2014-11-15
2      2013-12-21
2      2016-12-21
3      2015-09-21
3      2018-03-21
```

Table 2:

```
ID     log_time 
1      2011-10-12
1      2012-11-15
2      2012-12-21
2      2017-12-21
3      2014-09-21
3      2019-03-21
```

I want to get rows of Table 2 which are below min(log_time) of Table1 for each ID.
The result should be like this:

```
ID     log_time 
1      2011-10-12
1      2012-11-15
2      2012-12-21
3      2015-09-21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `join` and aggregation:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2 join
     (select t1.id, min(t1.log_time) as min_log_time
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.id
     ) t1
     on t2.id = t.id and t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp;
```

You can also express this as a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.log_time < (select min(t1.log_time) from t1 where t1.id = t2.id);
```

Note that both of these formulations will return no rows for ids missing from `table1` (which is quite consistent with your question).